# Email administrator when a duplicate IP is found on the network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scripting, network-monitoring

It was suggested that I ask this question on serverfault. I know this is a bit of a custom requirement but I was hoping someone currently has (or can put together) a script that checks for duplicate IP addresses on a network (something that might occur when someone assigns their own static IP when that lease has already been handed out via DHCP).

I know that it would be better to simply prevent them from changing it but with students coming in with their own laptops, etc, this is often a problem. I only have a single classroom with about 20 students so once I know the IP (that is duplicate) and preferably the hostname, I can take the necessary steps.

Emailing the alert is ideal because I can get it when I am out of the classroom and on my mobile.

P.S: I thought maybe grep'ing the DHCP log for NACKs might be a good idea?

Comment: What you have tried yourself this far? What I mean by this is that you might attract more/better answers by showing your own scripting efforts this far, instead of just asking someone to do all the coding for you.

Comment: You can reduce the risk of collisions by choosing an IP range for DHCP, which is less likely to have been configured manually. Ranges such as 192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.100.0/24 are very frequently used. 10.128.39.0/24 is less frequently used, thus less risk of collisions. Moreover you can configure a /16 for the network and a subrange for DHCP intended to be as difficult to type as possible. If you pick 10.x.0.0/16 for your network and 10.x.197.102 - 10.x.197.254 for DHCP, people are less likely to pick one of those manually.

Answer (score 1):

One tool that could be useful for detecting issues like this is [arpalert](http://www.arpalert.org/arpalert.html).  When installed on a Linux box that sees all/most of the traffic for a subnet (router/firewall), it will keep track of all the IP to MAC associations.  A duplicate address would be seen as IP address changing between mac addresses as each system tried to reply to ARPs for that IP.

Arpalert include the ability to define scripts that will be run on events like a mac change (see the `action on detect` option).  So you could compose a script that sends an email, or some other alert as needed.

Comment: [Script example](http://www.sesser.eu/howtos/arpalert.php)

Comment: Awesome, thats exactly what I am looking for, thanks for the suggestion and the script example! I will implement this immediately :)